# Subsetting ggplot2 graph using facet_grid()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to get individual trajectories and fitted trajectory per group across repeated measurements.

Toy data below:

```
set.seed(124)
ID <- factor(rep(1:21, times = 3))
Group <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times = 21)
score <- rnorm(63, 25, 3)
session <- rep(c("s1","s2", "s3"), each = 21)

df <- data.frame(ID, Group, session, score)
```

Now plot trajectories across the three repeated measures for each individual and derive a fitted slope for the whole sample.

```
c <- ggplot(df, aes(x = session, y = score, group = ID, colour = ID)) +
            geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + 
            stat_smooth(aes(group = 1), se = FALSE, method = "lm", color = "red")

c
```

Now I want to break this plot up into three plots by group. There is the long way where you subset the dataframe by group and do three separate graphs, However I would like to do it all in one graph, same as above, except separated by group. I tried:

```
c + facet_grid(.~Group)
```

But it comes out blank. Something is missing here and I don't know what it is.

Comment: if your `aes`, there is no need to reference the data.frame. Delete the `df$`s

Comment: Also, unless you want `ID` to be treated as a continuous variable, use `group=factor(ID), colour=factor(ID)`.

Comment: does it work for you now (does for me)?

Comment: It does! Thankyou. Can't understand it though. I got it to work months ago without turning ID into a factor for an almost identical facetted plot, except with two groups. I thought the number of groups might have been the issue. Still confused. But that worked so thank you @eipi10.

Comment: It will work without turning `ID` into a factor (you just have to follow @RichardTelford's advice about removing `df$` inside `aes`). But you'll get a continuous color gradient for `ID`, because it will be treated as numeric, rather than as categorical.

Comment: I see so the thing stopping the faceting was the `$` sign inside aes. Most illuminating thanks!